# Global Scope and While loop Scope- JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Why `var ProductArr=[]` is not accessible inside the `while` loop, and how can I access it?

What is the solution if I want to continue the array and reinitialize every time in a loop?

Also is there any way I can access the `var ProductArr=[]' variable inside while?

```
        var productArr = [];
        while(await page.$(".paging-next.ng-star-inserted .iconAct-Chevron_Right")){
          var grabProducts = await page.evaluate(() => {
            let products = document.querySelectorAll(".ng-tns-c226-3.ng-trigger.ng-trigger-staggerFadeInOut.product-grid .shelfProductTile-description a");       
            //var productArr = [];
            products.forEach(tag => {
                productArr.push(i+' '+tag.innerText) 
                i++;           
            });
            return productArr;
        });
        await page.click(".paging-next.ng-star-inserted .iconAct-Chevron_Right");
        await page.waitForTimeout(5000);
      }
```

Comment: Can you create a Fiddle?

Comment: @LajosArpad Puppeteer or phantomjs won't run in a fiddle